# Side box shadows are cut off when container is scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of cards where each card is a `div` and has a `box-shadow`. Cards container is a scrollable div. I don't know how to achieve to keep shadows on the left and right side, check screenshot. Card container `.content` needs to be aligned with footer content `.footer`.

[image]

```css
.page{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 600px;
  background: white;
  padding: 100px;
}

.content {
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  background: white;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  /* padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-right: -50px; */
}

.content > * + * {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.card{
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0 50px;
  width: 220px;
  background: #dde2eb;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(33, 49, 74, 0.25);
}

.footer{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="card">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dui justo, luctus quis elit in, lobortis vestibulum metus. Quisque pellentesque volutpat nisi in mattis.
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dui justo, luctus quis elit in, lobortis vestibulum metus. Quisque pellentesque volutpat nisi in mattis.
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dui justo, luctus quis elit in, lobortis vestibulum metus. Quisque pellentesque volutpat nisi in mattis.
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dui justo, luctus quis elit in, lobortis vestibulum metus. Quisque pellentesque volutpat nisi in mattis.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer placeholder
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code like below:

```css
.page{
  max-width: 600px;
  background: white;
  padding: 50px;
}

.content {
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  background: white;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
/* added */
.content::before,
.content::after {
  content:"";
  min-width:30px;
}
/**/
.content > * + * {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.card{
  padding: 0 50px;
  width: 220px;
  background: #dde2eb;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(33, 49, 74, 0.25);
}

.footer{
  background: yellow;
  margin:0 30px; /* added */
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="card">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dui justo, luctus quis elit in, lobortis vestibulum metus. Quisque pellentesque volutpat nisi in mattis.
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dui justo, luctus quis elit in, lobortis vestibulum metus. Quisque pellentesque volutpat nisi in mattis.
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dui justo, luctus quis elit in, lobortis vestibulum metus. Quisque pellentesque volutpat nisi in mattis.
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dui justo, luctus quis elit in, lobortis vestibulum metus. Quisque pellentesque volutpat nisi in mattis.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer placeholder
  </div>
</div>
```

If you adjust the scrollbar it will look better (available only on webkit browsers)

```css
.page{
  max-width: 600px;
  background: white;
  padding: 50px;
}

.content {
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  background: white;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
/* added */
.content::before,
.content::after {
  content:"";
  min-width:30px;
}
/**/
.content > * + * {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.card{
  padding: 0 50px;
  width: 220px;
  background: #dde2eb;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(33, 49, 74, 0.25);
}

.footer{
  background: yellow;
  margin:0 30px; /* added */
}

/* Let's get this party started */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
}
 
/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 10px;
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background:linear-gradient(to right,transparent 30px,grey 0 calc(100% - 30px), transparent 0);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4); 
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="card">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dui justo, luctus quis elit in, lobortis vestibulum metus. Quisque pellentesque volutpat nisi in mattis.
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dui justo, luctus quis elit in, lobortis vestibulum metus. Quisque pellentesque volutpat nisi in mattis.
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dui justo, luctus quis elit in, lobortis vestibulum metus. Quisque pellentesque volutpat nisi in mattis.
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dui justo, luctus quis elit in, lobortis vestibulum metus. Quisque pellentesque volutpat nisi in mattis.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer placeholder
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The same issue as in another answer. I know about this solution. The issue here is that when you scroll, the cards and footer are not aligned https://imgur.com/a/VjopYPv

Comment: @Matt well, how you want to show and hide something at the same time? this is impossible, if you want to show the shadow then the element should also show otherwise how the scroll should behave?

Comment: I don't want to hide anything. I just want to show shadows for cards and have aligned design. I believe side shadows can be made by a pseudo element of card container, but I am wondering if there is better solution.

Comment: @Matt if you want to *show* something (like shadow) then on scroll you will for sure *show* everything else. How you want to keep the card aligned (hide them on scroll) and at the same tike show only their shadows?

Comment: There are missing only two shadows. The left shadow on the first card and right shadow on the last card. You can create the left shadow and the right shadow with pseduelements of the card container. They should hide as you scroll. This would be possible by using some javascript. Maybe this is not possible with only css. Interesting, I thought there some easy only css way but perhpas its not.

Comment: @Matt *They should hide as you scroll.* --> how they shoud hide? in the code I provided, they actually hide on scroll. You need to be more explicit ... *This would be possible by using some javascript.* --> show us how you would do it with JS so we can understand the behavior and try to find a CSS only solution

Comment: I am too busy now, but I will post my solution if nobody will post it here at some point.

Comment: Damn, sorry. I was working too much last days and didn't think about this properly. The effect I am thinking of wouldn't be nice. Sorry, I was confused. I will award your answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

```css
      .page{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 600px;
  background: white;
  padding: 100px;
}

.content {
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  background: white;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  /* padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-right: -50px; */
}
.card {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.card-inner{
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0 50px;
  width: 220px;
  background: #dde2eb;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(33, 49, 74, 0.25);
}

.footer{
  background: yellow;
padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-inner">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dui justo, luctus quis elit in, lobortis vestibulum metus. Quisque pellentesque volutpat nisi in mattis.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-inner">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dui justo, luctus quis elit in, lobortis vestibulum metus. Quisque pellentesque volutpat nisi in mattis.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-inner">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dui justo, luctus quis elit in, lobortis vestibulum metus. Quisque pellentesque volutpat nisi in mattis.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-inner">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dui justo, luctus quis elit in, lobortis vestibulum metus. Quisque pellentesque volutpat nisi in mattis.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      Footer placeholder
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that card container needs to be aligned with Footer.

Comment: add `padding-left` and `padding-right` to `20px`

Comment: where should be padding-left and padding-right?

Comment: `.footer` class

Comment: it breaks the layout

Comment: after adding `padding` in `.footer` class?

Comment: You already added padding in `.footer`. Right shadow is cut off in your solution.

Comment: The footer is aligned when you don't scroll. As soon as you start scrolling, the footer is not aligned with cards. Check this screenshot https://imgur.com/a/vxeM8x2

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by simply adding padding to the container.

```css
.page{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 600px;
  background: white;
  padding: 100px;
}

.content {
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  background: white;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  /* padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-right: -50px; */
}

.content > * + * {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.card{
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0 50px;
  width: 220px;
  background: #dde2eb;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(33, 49, 74, 0.25);
}

.footer{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="card">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dui justo, luctus quis elit in, lobortis vestibulum metus. Quisque pellentesque volutpat nisi in mattis.
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dui justo, luctus quis elit in, lobortis vestibulum metus. Quisque pellentesque volutpat nisi in mattis.
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dui justo, luctus quis elit in, lobortis vestibulum metus. Quisque pellentesque volutpat nisi in mattis.
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dui justo, luctus quis elit in, lobortis vestibulum metus. Quisque pellentesque volutpat nisi in mattis.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer placeholder
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Card container `.content` needs to be aligned with footer content `.footer`.